# C# - public getter and protected setter interface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface, protected

Hello i'm working on a Unity game and i would like to create living entities.

To perform this, i want to create an interface for all entities having health

Here is my interface for LivingEntities:

```
public interface ILivingEntity
{
    public float Hp { get; protected set; }
    public float MaxHp { get; protected set; }
    public float HpRegenPerSecond { get; protected set; }

    public event EventHandler Event_died;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        MaxHp = Hp;
    }

    protected virtual void receiveDamage(IAttack attackSource)
    {
        Hp -= attackSource.damage;
        watchForEntityDeadOrNot();
    }

    protected abstract void watchForEntityDeadOrNot();

    protected void regenHp()
    {
        Hp += Time.deltaTime * HpRegenPerSecond;
        if (Hp > MaxHp)
            Hp = MaxHp;
    }
}
```

The point is:

- I need the hp to be public in get
- I want to give code in my interface for the hp regeneration per second (to not re implement the same code in each living entity)
- I want the hp to be set only from the living entities themself

I saw tricks like this:

in interface:

```
public float Hp{get;}
```

and in implementation:

```
public float Hp{
  get{code...}
  protected set{code...}
}
```

but in my case, if i define the setter only in the child class implementation, i'm not able to give any code for my 'regenHp' method in interface.

How to perform this ?

Comment: You probably want to create an abstract class rather than try to force this logic into the interface.

Comment: Correct, but my classe already derivate from 'MonoBehaviour' and C# seems not to accept multi inheritance

Comment: Then you can create an abstract class that derives from the 'MonoBehaviour' instead. And then in your child instance derive from the abstract class only

Comment: It's what i thought, but if i want to create another 'property' like IFightingEntity' i cannot make both? (probably linked to the design pattern decoator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using an abstract base class as was suggested in a comment, you can leverage Unity's built in component design which is the standard way of solving such a problem.  Its common for game objects to be composed of many components.

You can define a shared component like:

```
public class LivingComponent : MonoBehavior
{
    ...
}
```

And then depend on it in your main components:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(LivingComponent))]
public class SomeLivingThing : MonoBehavior {}
```

And if its important that you still have a read-only interface, you can do that too:

```
public interface ILivingEntity {
   // Getters only here
}

public class LivingComponent : MonoBehavior, ILivingEntity {
   // Implementation
}

// In some other code:
var hp = obj.GetComponent<ILivingEntity>().Hp;
```

Comment: Ok it fit to my problem. I wanted to reduce my object components but it is probably a bad idea in game development.

Thanks !

Comment: It can be hard to transition to using composition over inheritance if you're used to inheritance, but trust me its very important to learn, and in my experience the majority of time composition yields much better code.